# java lang illegal argument exception?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

when i try to start my servlet the program give me the followings error :

```
    ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: 
    Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Employees.war".PARSE: 
    org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service 
    jboss.deployment.unit."Employees.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process 
    phase PARSE of deployment "Employees.war"
    at 
    org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start
    (DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at 
    org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService
    (ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run
    (ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEE0040: A component named 
    'DipendenteEJB' is already defined in this module
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEModuleDescription.addComponent
    (EEModuleDescription.java:167)
    at 
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.
    EJBComponentDescriptionFactory.addComponent
   (EJBComponentDescriptionFactory.java:58)
    at 
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.
    SessionBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.processSessionBeans
    (SessionBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.java:169)
    at 
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.
    SessionBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations
    (SessionBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.java:86)
    at  
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.
    AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.
    processAnnotations
    (AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:57)
    at 
    org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.
    AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy
    (AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:76)
    at 
    org.jboss.as.server.deployment.
    DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start
   (DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
```

Yesterday the project worked properly. Today, after creating a jar file containing the 2 ejb (local and remote) interfaces and inserting it into WEB-INF -> lib, the program gave me an error

Comment: "A component named 'DipendenteEJB' is already defined in this module" -- that seems to explain it fairly well.

Comment: @bradimus and how i can solve it?

Comment: "A component named 'DipendenteEJB' is already defined in this module" -- I'd suggest defining 'DipendenteEJB' only once. You'll have to dig through your files to find where it is defined.